# How well does Windows Phone support HTML5?

Tags: html, windows-phone-7

According to [this](http://html5test.com/results/mobile.html), Windows Phone support for HTML5 is not good (they're ranked last out of all platforms/browsers). This rating is based on HTML5 feature support, but I'm wondering whether the raw performance (rendering speed etc.) is at least up to the same standards as the other platforms.

Is HTML5 currently a viable choice for Windows Phone mobile apps?

Comment: Can you please delete this?  I can't bring myself to close it as not constructive.  If you care, I run a windows phone, and IE9 renders well, but it seems a little slow relative to other applications on the phone.  So, yes, it is a viable choice.  If that's a test I can run on mine, let me know and I can get you some results.  Otherwise... you're killing me.

Comment: I have an HTC Trophy with Mango, it is at least 50% faster/better than my Motorola Milestone (Original Droid) with respect to mobile browsing. How much of that is HTML5, I can't say, but I'm sure some of it is. That said, jQuery Mobile support is pretty good, and for me, that has been enough.

Comment: Looking deeper http://html5test.com/compare/browser/wp80/wp75/ios50.html the question will be moot by the fourth quarter of this year.  The website is pretty thorough in what is, and is not, supported.  So if you *need* a particular feature of HTML5, you will know if 7.5 supports it.  Otherwise, if you're just talking about rendering speed, I don't think you have anything to worry about.

Comment: @Will: I don't understand why I'm killing you with this. Either it's not constructive, in which case you should go ahead and close it (I won't be offended), or else it *is* constructive.

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed? It is quite valid IMO. Anyhow, yes, HTML5 is a viable choice for WP7 development, see the following: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/property-finder-the-first-html5-based-windows-phone-7-application/

Comment: @ColinE:  Read this: *"Is HTML5 currently a viable choice for Windows Phone mobile apps?"* then the close reason below.